# How to set permissions for all collaborators in a protected range, or set default permissions?

Tags: google-sheets, permissions

I find the "protect range" function in Google Spreadsheets very useful, but I have one problem: I often need to set **all** of the collaborators' permissions to, for example, "Can comment."

[image: screenshot]

It is very tedious to set them manually all at once, so is there any way to set *all* of the permissions to "Can comment"?

Or, is there any way to change the default permissions for a protected range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script for this, since there doesn't seem to be any way.

To use it, double click the first contributor in the lists's permission selector thing, and then just press right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Every time you press right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, the next contributor's permissions will become "Can comment." After it reaches the last one, simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to close the dialog (or right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> works too). Press right <kbd>Win</kbd> to  end the script.

```
#NoEnv
RCtrl::
SendInput {Down}{Down}{Enter}{Tab}
Return
RWin::ExitApp
```